# Polynomial fit and Fourier transform plot

Tags: fitting, polynomials, fourier-analysis

I'm pretty new to Mathematica so excuse me for obvious questions. 
I have a dataset, second column contains invoice amount and the first column contains days passed between each invoice date starting at 0 (time data but not uniform spaced).

I'm trying to fit a polynomial function that best represents this data, apply a Fourier transform, and then plot the Fourier transform. I'm mainly aiming to catch weird invoice frequencies using the Fourier transform.

How would one go about this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full data: [Full Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1sv6nex5x64h3t/semerkand.xlsx?dl=0)

I used this code from one of the users here to fit a simple sin curve

```
len = Subtract @@ data[[{-1, 1}, 1]];
funcfunc = Fit[data, Table[Sin[(π n)/len x], {n, 1, 50}], x];
Show[
  ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[funcfunc, {x, 0, len}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}}]]`
```

Would an $n$th degree polynomial fit be better?

Assuming I go ahead with this code and the sin series fit how would I plot the Fourier transform of the fit?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far so we can help you get past where you're currently stuck.

Comment: I edited the original post with what I've done so far.

Comment: I don't see a polynomial fit in your code. You seem to be fitting a Fourier sine series. The coefficients of a Fourier series approximate the Fourier transform of a sampled function.

Comment: You have some repeat "days passed between each invoice date" values which you should address.

Comment: Generally, avoid polynomial fits unless you understand why they are treacherous. Fitting Fourier series directly makes more sense, and Fourier fits are tamer beasts.

Comment: @MikeY those are same day invoices, that's why days passed is 0 among those. should I get rid of them to smooth the data?

Comment: Shouldn't they be added together then? Not clear to me...probably handled correctly in your Fit[ ] you are doing so I guess it is fine.

Comment: @MikeY they are different invoices but I might add them together to lessen the points since there seem to be a bit much atm for a decent fit.

Comment: @JohnDoty thanks for the comment John. I also feel like the Fourier Series represent it better but how do I go from here to plotting a Fourier transform plot? I changed zhk's code below with my fit variable funcfunc but I seem to get a Nintegrate error.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on "days between". So the full time history of invoices is `Accumulate[daysBetweenData]`? Or is each "days between" value from time 0 to that value?

Comment: Each value is from time 0 to that value. When you subtract consecutive values together you get the actual days in between, sorry for the confusion. I also have the dates for each invoice, not the hour/min info though. I couldn't get the date format to work with fit so I used the days between values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something for you to experiment with

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\zhk\\Desktop\\data.txt", "Data"];

NF = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   a*x^7 + b*x^4 + c*x^3 + d*x^2 + e*x + f, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, x];

Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[NF[x], {x, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

```
FT = FourierTransform[NF[x], x, \[Omega]]

Plot[Evaluate@Abs@FT, {\[Omega], -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The `FourierTransform` plot doesn't make any sense to me but this is a sample exactly doing what you asked for.

Comment: This is great for a starting point but as you said FourierTransform does not make much sense. I'm guessing the fit needs a bit more peaks like a sine series as @JohnDoty mentioned above. BTW whenever I try to change the NF in your last two lines of code with funcfunc (fit variable from my code) I get an NIntegrate error. What might be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts on your data.

```
data = Import["semerkand.xlsx"][[1]];
data[[1]]
```

> {"DAYS BETWEEN", "AMOUNT"}

Now let's plot the DAYS BETWEEN and the AMOUNT against point number

```
ListLinePlot[data[[2 ;; -1, 1]]]
ListLinePlot[data[[2 ;; -1, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I guess you have sorted your data so that small DAYS BETWEEN are at the start of the data. What appears to happen is that you get a small value invoice followed by a large value invoice followed by a small value invoice...

What are you actually trying to do? There is no point in trying to look at Fourier because you only have 2 points in a cycle. Do you wish to put a mean line through the data to even out the small, large, small fluctuation?

Comment: I haven't arranged the data actually. These are the invoices of a customer starting from 2012. Some small value invoices might be for a different product and that is why there are regular gaps like 28-30 days between invoices and some very unusual amount like 0 days or 1 days. Overall, I'm just trying to do some analysis for accounts receivable of different customers and to identify these kinds of anomalies. My boss suggested this Polynomial Fit and Fourier Transform approach as he is an electrical engineer and thus my questions regarding these.

Comment: Do you also have data for the actual time the invoice came in? If so this would give a time history which is more straightforward to analyse for periodicy.

Comment: I only have the dates not the hour/min info if that's what you're asking.

Comment: The dates, together with invoice amounts, would be best for a frequency analysis.

Comment: So do you suggest to get rid of fourier transform and go with say just a DATELINEPLOT?

Comment: A DATELINEPLOT is a good starting point. I always look at the raw data and see if I can detect intiresting trends by eye. Then I look to quantify or model them.